# Pandas, search which values of column of dataframe1 are in column of dataframe2, and in which row

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe

I have, in `df1`, a dataframe of dates.

```
0   03/01/2007
1   16/02/2007
2   16/03/2007
3   20/04/2007
4   18/05/2007
```

In `df2` I have a continuos time serie (daily).

```
        Date  DailyEquity
1 2007-01-04          0.0
2 2007-01-05         -5.0
3 2007-01-06          0.0
4 2007-01-07          0.0
5 2007-01-08          5.0
```

These are separate dataframes since `df2` is longer than `df1`.

I'd like to generate a column in `df2` such that it contains `1` if Date is present in `df1`, and `0` if `Date` is not present in `df1`. Is this possible without writing loops?

I know of `np.where()` and other pandas functions that would help in this, if the 2 dataframes were of the same length. Is this possible?

Wanted result:

```
        Date  DailyEquity  Column
1 2007-01-04          0.0  0    # <-- "2007-01-04" is not in df1
2 2007-01-05         -5.0  0    # <-- "2007-01-05" is not in df1
3 2007-01-06          0.0  0    # <-- ecc...
4 2007-01-07          0.0  0    # <-- "1" if date is in df1
5 2007-01-08          5.0  0
```

Comment: `df2['Date'].isin(df1['Date']).astype(int)`

Comment: Wasn't aware of isin, it works, thanks! Feel free to post as answer.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use `isin` method to check that a value present in a list

```
df2['Date'].isin(df1['Date']).astype(int)
```